# Show Associated Model Data with React Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm using the react-rails gem and have two models: `Message` and `User`. User has_many :messages.

In my `message.js.jsx`, I'd like to show the User of that message. In regular erb, it'd just be `<%= message.user.name %>`. How would I do this in the `message.js.jsx` component?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* rename your component to `message.js.jsx.erb` and use ERB in it, but it will only be compiled once when Rails starts up.

A more React-ish way to handle is to AJAX load the user data in `componentDidMount` (or a Store, if using Flux).

**message.js.jsx**

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { user: { name: '' } };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  $.getJSON('/users/'+ this.props.id +'.json', function(userData) {
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({ user: userData })
    }
  });
},
```

You can create a Rails endpoint to return userData as JSON something like this:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # default html response
    format.json { render json: @user.to_json(only: [:id, :name]) }
  end
end
```

See [Facebook's page on this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Unixmonkey that is the react way. You can also do it a few more ways.

```
@user = JSON.parse user.to_json(include: [:messages], only: [:id, :name])
```

As well as using componentDidMount to hit a JSON endpoint using jbuilder which you can put a timeout on if you want to update dynamically.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $.getJSON('/users/'+ this.props.id +'.json', function(user) {
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({ user: user })
    }
  });
},
```

Your show.json.jbuilder under user views would look something like this:

```
  json.id @user.id
  json.name @user.name
  json.messages @user.messages do |message|
    json.id message.id
    json.content message.content
    json.created_at message.created_at
  end
```